# Extract all data within quotes and make a list

Tags: python, regex

Hello I am trying to extract all data from my txt file:

```
[2018-07-10 15:04:11] USER INPUT "hello"
[2018-07-10 15:04:12] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Hello! How are you doing today"
[2018-07-10 15:04:42] USER INPUT "I am doing good thank you"
[2018-07-10 15:04:42] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Good to know"
```

in a way that I just have the data from double quotes in a list

```
["hello","Hello! How are you doing today","I am doing good thank you","Good to know"]
```

I am trying to use

```
corpus_raw = ""
for log_filename in log_filenames:
    print("Reading '{0}'...".format(log_filename))
    with codecs.open(log_filename, "rb", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as log_file:

        corpus_raw += log_file.read()
    corpus_raw= re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]\s+', corpus_raw)
    print("Corpus is now {0} characters long".format(len(corpus_raw)))
    print()
```

but I am not able to get any results with that.
Any suggestions will help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.*?`:

```
import re
contents = [re.findall('"(.*?)"', i.strip('\n'))[0] for i in open('filename.txt')]
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'Hello! How are you doing today', 'I am doing good thank you', 'Good to know']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split `corpus_raw` by `"` and get every other item within the list:

```
corpus_raw = ""
for log_filename in log_filenames:
    print("Reading '{0}'...".format(log_filename))
    with codecs.open(log_filename, "rb", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as log_file:

        corpus_raw += log_file.read()
    print("Corpus is now {0} characters long".format(len(corpus_raw)))
    print()
corpus_raw = corpus_raw.split('"')[1::2]
```

`corpus_raw` would become (given your sample input):

```
['hello', 'Hello! How are you doing today', 'I am doing good thank you', 'Good to know']
```

Comment: I get error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: My answer should replace your `corpus_raw= re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]\s+', corpus_raw)` line, not adding to it.

Comment: Or you can simply do `corpus_raw = logfile.read().split('"')[1::2]` instead of `corpus_raw += logfile.read()`.

Comment: Hello! I did that but I got- TypeError: must be str, not list. I have updated my code a little more so you can see exactly what I have before too

Comment: I see. Since you keep appending to `corpus_raw` as a string in a loop, you should not process it until the loop ends, since after the processing it becomes a list. I've updated my answer to put the processing outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks a ton this helped!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Remember to mark the answer you find to be the most helpful as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
$ cut -d'"' -f2 < so.txt
hello
Hello! How are you doing today
I am doing good thank you
Good to know
```